# Database and table are not created in the SpringBoot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I have checked all the dependencies and added SQL Driver as well. I am using the MYSQL database. After running the Spring Boot application DB is not created. I am using the Data Management tool in STS4.

I expect that the `CitizenDB` database and database table `Citizen` will be created because I have added all necessary properties to the `application.yml` configuration file

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CitizenService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CitizenService</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.yml:

```yaml
server:
  port: 8081
    
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CitizenDB
    username: root
    password: March@031996
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver  
  application:
    name: CITIZEN-SERVICE
    jpa:
     show-sql: true
     database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLInnoDBDialect
     generate-ddl: true  
     hibernate:
       ddl-auto: update
```

Entity class:

```java
package com.example.demo.CitizenService.Entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Citizen {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private int vaccinationId;
}
```

Main class:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class CitizenServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CitizenServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please include well-formatted code in your question, which may be easily copy-pasted for to reproduce your issue.

Use separated code blocks for different files and types of files especially. Your `application.yml` configuration is completely unreadable.

Remove any text lines like `enter code here package com.example.demo.CitizenService;` or `ENTITY CLASS:`. They make your code uncompilable. Use comments and javadocs instead. However, if you don't want to do that, you may add the flag

Use code formatting in your IDE. [Example for IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_file).

Second, please clearly specify your issue and what exactly you have done to resolve it. I'm assuming you expect that your Spring Boot application should create the database `CitizenDB` and the `Citizen` table in it.

Spring (more specifically Hibernate) doesn't create a database by default and it's a bad practice. It assumes that you already have a created database and better to create it yourself. However, if you still want to create the database automatically you may specify such flag `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` in your data source URL. Example for your case:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CitizenDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

You have to improve excluding of the `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` class since you want the Spring to configure everything for you. Your main class should look like this:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class CitizenServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CitizenServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I tried as you said Actually I added (exclude =  {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }) this when I got this error 
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Comment: @SaiChakra Which error did you get? Please add steps to reproduce your issue and application logs for your run to the question. If you exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`, you would need to configure all data source related Spring beans manually.

Comment: Hi @Alexander Golovnya thanks for your help my error got resolved.Even not mentioning this statement :                                                                                   
     url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CitizenDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true"                  I just mentioned    url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CitizenDB.                                           But I removed {exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class}) this worked for me Thanks alot.

Comment: @SaiChakra Great, I'm glad that this helped you resolve your issue. Please don't forget to accept the answer and mention the solution in your question to help others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You just add createDatabaseIfNotExist=true like this

```
spring
    datasource
        url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CitizenDB?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
```

to your application.yml file

Comment: It's a bad practice and still won't work because the author excluded `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`